# Who are the Saptamata?

Tags: scripture, puranas

What is the basis of classifying the “Saptamata”?Where do we find this categorization?

Those I’ve heard are:

1)Atma mata(your own mother)

2)Guru patni (Wife of guru)

3)Queen of your country

4)Brahmin Patni

5)Earth(Bhumi)

6)Dhaatri(foster mother?)

Can anyone correct and complete the list also?

Comment: Interesting but where did you read about this concept?

Comment: @Rickross I heard an acharya of Shaiva vishishtaadvait casually quote this in a YouTube lecture of his;I will get the link.

Comment: okay .... @amethyst

Answer (score 2):

#### Yes, there's a notion of 'Sapta Mātā' or 'the Seven-Mothers'.

Śrīla Prabhupada in the Purport to [ŚB 7.12.8](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/7/12/8/) quotes the relevant verses as follows:-

> There are seven kinds of mothers:
>
> आदौ माता गुरोः पत्नी ब्रह्मणी राजपत्निका ।
> धेनुर्धात्री तथा पृथ्वी सप्तैता मातरः स्मृताः ॥
>
> ātma-mātā guroḥ patnī brāhmaṇī rāja-patnikā 
> dhenur dhātrī tathā pṛthvī
> saptaitā mātaraḥ smṛtāḥ
>
> > These Seven Women are said to be Mother: 
> > 1. One's own Original Mother 
> > 2. the
> > Wife of the Teacher or Spiritual Master,
> > 3.  the Wife of a Brāhmiṇa, 
> > 4. the
> > King’s Wife,
> >  5. the Cow,
> >  6. the Nurse, and 
> >  7. the Earth.

Prabhupada quotes these references in various chapters in the Bhāgavatam.

Although, Śrīla Prabhupada doesn't cite any sources for these verses, he just quotes these verses as `"According to scriptures"`, for instance in [ŚB 1.11.28](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/1/11/28/)

Searching for the source of this verse, I finally ended at the Mahāsubhāṣitasaṃgraha

##### So this verse may be traced to the Mahāsubhāṣitasaṃgraha [Verse No. 4764](https://www.wisdomlib.org/sanskrit/quote/mss/subhashita-4764).

---

Interestingly, a variant of this verse may be found in the Cāṇakya-Nīti, but here we get a list of **'Pañca-Mātā' or 'the Five Mothers'**.

> राजपत्नी गुरोः पत्नी मित्रपत्नी तथैव च ।
>  पत्नीमाता स्वमाता च पञ्चैता
> मातरः स्मृताः ॥ ०५-२३ ॥
>
> [Verse 5.23](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_z_misc_major_works/chANakyanItisort.html).
>
> Know these five as the five mothers of a person:-
>
> > 1. Wife of the king,
> > 2. Wife of the teacher,
> > 3. Wife of the elder brother,
> > 4. The wife's mother and
> > 5. One's Own mother

---

Finally, a more **traditional list** of 'various Mothers' maybe found in the Brahmavaivarta Purāṇa [1.10.154-155](https://sa.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%88%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%96%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A7_(%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%96%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%83)/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A7%E0%A5%A6) as follows.

We get **'Caturdaśa-Mātā' or 'the fourteen Mothers'**.

> अन्नदातुश्च या पत्नी भगिनी गुरुकामिनी ।
>   माता च तत्सपत्नी च कन्या
> पुत्रप्रिया तथा ॥ १५४ ॥
>  मातुर्माता पितुर्माता श्वश्रूपित्रोः स्वसा तथा
> ।  
> पितृव्यस्त्री मातुलानी मातरश्च चर्तुदश ॥ १५५ ॥
>
> > Know these fourteen Women as Mothers:
> >
> > 1. The Wife of one who gives food or
> > 2. The Sister of one who gives food.
> > 3. Wife of a Teacher.
> > 4. Mother,
> > 5. Stepmother.
> > 6. Daughter.
> > 7. Daughter-in-Law.
> > 8. Mother's mother.
> > 9. Grandmother.
> > 10. Daughter-in-Law.
> > 11. Mother's sister.
> > 12. Father's sister.
> > 13. Aunt.
> > 14. Maternal aunt.
>
> [English Translation](https://archive.org/details/brahma-vaivarta-purana-all-four-kandas-english-translation/page/n57/mode/1up?view=theater) by Parimal Publications